# Image object detection question

Tags: object, edge-detection

I am about to start on a university project that is not part of any courses. I was tasked with identifying objects on a arbitrary image (say number of circles in a image). I will be working mostly with 2D images. I don't have much experience with such image processing and was wondering if someone could give a guidance on where to start.

My initial google search gave me some keywords to build upon, such as OpenCV. I have some courses regarding signals and systems (fourier transform in particular), lots of computer science related courses (data structures, algorithms, etc), math courses (calculus, linear algebra, etc), and others.

Can someone please give me a quick guide on what kind of things to look for and learn? Any kind of guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Read chapter 14 of Richard Szeleski's [new book](http://szeliski.org/Book/) ([PDF draft](http://szeliski.org/Book/drafts/SzeliskiBook_20100903_draft.pdf) available) for an overview of current techniques.

There's also material from a short conference course [here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/torralba/shortCourseRLOC/).

Answer (score 0):

Machine vision image processing is an extremely complex area.   I recommend the book Image Processing, Analysis, and Machine Vision by Milan Sonka.  An expensive tome, but unique in being oriented toward practical algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Some simple object such as Circles can be detected using Hough transform.
If you need some more advanced object detection you can use Viola-Jones algorithm (see e.g. OpenCV or Rapidminer http://spl.utko.feec.vutbr.cz/en/image-processing-extension-for-rapidminer-5) or Histogram of Oriented Gradients (is planet to http://spl.utko.feec.vutbr.cz/en/image-processing-extension-for-rapidminer-5)